# echo variable output in powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement, variables, path, echo

I am trying to echo/Write-Output variables in a powershell script. I have tried many diffent ways looking at many examples, and for some reason I just can't wrap my head around what's wrong here.

```
# Detect the location of this script
Set-Variable "GAMEPATH=(Get-Location).Path"
Write-Output $GAMEPATH

Set-Variable "GAMEEXE=game.exe"

# Make sure Game exists.

Write-Output ""
Write-Output "Step 1. Make sure the game exists!"
if (!(Test-Path $GAMEPATH) -and !(Test-Path $GAMEEXE)) {
    Write-Warning "'$GAMEEXE' absent from both locations"
  }
else 
{
    Write-Output "Step 1. Successful!"
}
```

I get an error "Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null." so I assume the path is not being passed through properley. Anyother feedback is apreciated as well!

Comment: `"GAMEPATH=(Get-Location).Path"` is just a literal string, nothing is getting resolved there and I'm uncertain why you think you need to use `Set-Variable` or `Write-Output` at all. Your code seems filled with misconceptions. Also "Detect the location of this script", then you want `$PSScriptRoot` for reliability

Comment: The proper way using `Set-Variable` would be `Set-Variable -Name GAMEPATH -Value (Get-Location).Path`. But actually it is more common and easier to write like this: `$GAMEPATH = (Get-Location).Path` ... without any quotes. ;-)